# How to get specific fields of a Foreign key in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

So I've been learning django and I decided to make a blog with comments.
Here are my models:

```
class Author(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name = 'e-mail')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):

    author = models.OneToOneField(Author)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    text = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author + "commented"
```

Now,In my template,I can't access the name of the author.It just shiws the comment.{{comment.author.name}} doesn't work.

Here's the template block.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="post">
    {% if post.published_date %}
        <div class="date">
            {{ post.published_date }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url "post_edit" pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <h1>{{ post.title }}-{{post.author}}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.text|linebreaks }}</p>
</div>
{% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="date">
            {{ comment.post_date }}
        </div>
        <h4>Author:{{comment.author.name}}</h4>
        <h5>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</h5>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<h3>New Comment</h3>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

ViewCode

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            author = Author.objects.create()
            author.name = request.user
            author.email = ""
            comment.author = author
            comment.post = post
            comment.post_date = timezone.now()
            comment.save()
            return redirect('/posts/'+pk+'/')

    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.order_by('post_date')    
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'post': post, 'comments':      comments, 'form': form})
```

Comment: @PauloPessoa Done :D

Comment: what happening when you do this {{comment.author}} ?

Comment: @PauloPessoa It doesn't show amything.I basically get "Author-" .Its the with {{post.author}} as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
author = Author.objects.create()
author.name = request.user
author.email = ""
comment.author = author
```

You create the author, but don't save the name and email.

try this:

```
author = Author.objects.create(name=request.user, email="")
comment.author = author
```

or this:

```
author = Author.objects.create()
author.name = request.user
author.email = ""
author.save()
comment.author = author.pk
```

Comment: Can you check in the database, if the name is ok? and the comment has the author_id with the user.

Comment: I checked.I hadn't typed the code from your answer correctly xD.It worked now!Thanks!